# MultiLine output text - properties - text is printing as single line

Tags: taipy

i have a question:

i read text from a textfile which looks like this:

> Item1

> Item2

> Item3

> Item4

```
def collect_contents(path):
    print("coll")
    f = open(path, "r")
    logdata = f.read()
    f.close()
    return logdata

def load_contents(path):
    print("load")
    logdata = collect_contents(path)
    print(logdata)
    return logdata`
```

and it prints() in in the stdout like this: 
2023/11/26 13:06:09 stdout  Item4 
2023/11/26 13:06:09 stdout  Item3 
2023/11/26 13:06:09 stdout  Item2 
2023/11/26 13:06:09 stdout  Item1

but unfortunately this code:

```
def update_content(state):
    print("update content")
    path = "...path... "
    state.content = load_contents(path)

index = """
#MULTILINE-TEXT
<|ReloadButton|button|on_action=button_pressed|>
#MulitLineTextFromTXTFile
<|{content}|text|>
#MulitLineTextFromTXTFile2
<|{content}|text|raw=True|>
#MulitLineTextFromTXTFile3
<|{content}|text|mode="e;pre"e;:|>
"""

app = Gui(page=index)
```

leads to this:

[MulitLineTextFromTXTFile
Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4
MulitLineTextFromTXTFile2
Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4
MulitLineTextFromTXTFile3
Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qH7dS.png)

So my question: -Why are the line-breaks lost?
What am i missing here?
I want to have the Items listed as in the text file..

What would be the character to new line since  < br > and "\n" in python won't work...

I was hoping the "raw" or mode="e;pre"e;: would help me keep the line breaks as described here:

https://docs.taipy.io/en/release-2.2/manuals/gui/viselements/text/

```
#MULTILINE-TEXT
<|ReloadButton|button|on_action=button_pressed|>
#MulitLineTextFromTXTFile
<|{content}|text|>
#MulitLineTextFromTXTFile2
<|{content}|text|raw=True|>
#MulitLineTextFromTXTFile3
<|{content}|text|mode="e;pre"e;:|>
```

Thanks in advance you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exists an open [issue](https://github.com/Avaiga/taipy-gui/issues/951) on this. It would be soon done. For now, replace your text visual elements by an input visual element like this:

`<|{your_text}|input|multiline|class_name=fullwidth|>`

Not editable:

`<|{your_text}|input|multiline|active=False|class_name=fullwidth|>`

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!! This is exactly what i needed and works just like a charm!!